# Is there a Dotclear to WXR convertor that can be used to import comments into Disqus?

Tags: wordpress, disqus

Are there any scripts (any language) to convert comments from Dotclear (2.4.2) blog export files to the Wordpress WXR format?

This is so that I can then use that WXR format file to import comments into Disqus.  I'm moving from Dotclear to a different blogging system where I'll be using Disqus for the comments.  This is just for the comments, the posts are moved directly to the new blog.

It looks straightforward enough to extract the comments from the Dotclear export file, and using the post id, associate them with the URL of the original post, and then put that in a skeleton WXR file.  But I don't want to re-invent the wheel, if this already exists.

Comment: No response, so I went ahead and created a WXR file from the Dotclear file.  But the Disqus import process is so slow (days) and opaque (no error messages when it rejects it) I gave up after a couple of attempts.  It's clearly not worth using Disqus or Livefyre for a site that has existing comments, until or unless they get around to caring about finishing their import development.